# How can you reverse an Array without using the reverse method in AS3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, action, reverse

How can you reverse an array without using the `reverse()` method?

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var _reversedList:Array = new Array();      

    public function Main()
    {   
        var yourShoppingList:Array = ["Milk","Bread","Eggs","Cereal","Cheese","Ham"];
        shoppingList(yourShoppingList);
        trace("The original array was " + yourShoppingList + " and now it is reversed as " + _reversedList + ".");
    }

    private function shoppingList(items:Array):Array {
        while(items.length){
            var lastItem:String = items.pop();
            _reversedList.unshift(lastItem);
        }
        return _reversedList;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. I tried using `_reversedList.unshift(items.pop());` but it was giving me an error, so I ended up creating a variable, and now it seems fine? But regardless, it's not reversing the Array, and I'm not sure why.

Thank you for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

*NOTE: For those of you who are Full Sail students, feel free to reference this, but don't copy / paste, as the teachers know about this post and you'll probably be penalized for cheating. Just a friendly warning.

Comment: erm, why dont you want to use reverse()?

Comment: That's my opinion. I'm taking a class, and they don't want us to use reverse(). It's stupid. @.@

Comment: btw, shouldn't you be doing a counted loop like: var len:uint=items.length; for(var i:uint=0; i<len; i++){...} ... the function in question should get stuck in infinite loop!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
_reversedList.unshift(lastItem);
```

to

```
_reversedList.push(lastItem);
```

works for me. Taking the last item and pushing it in as the first item on the new array.